# EXE not running, accidental change in configuration?

Tags: c#, .net, exe

I've been working on a simple project that uses some common .NET classes, isolated storage, some resources and no external libraries.

Somehow the EXE generated (either in debug or release mode) no longer runs (stops working as soon as it's opened) without giving any details or displaying any exceptions.

It runs normally in visual studio, and there's a .application in the same folder that when clicked starts in install process.

I'm not interested in installation files, I just want it to be the way it was: running an EXE (it's easier to get testers when all you have to do is running it).

I have previous versions of the program, and all of them run normally through the EXE's.

I don't recall changing anything regarding framework, deployment or build. I revised it and there's nothing changed apart from using new objects from the .NET framework.

--[Update]--
Just checked the event viewer. Event data "not available" and answer "not available".

Comment: What does your VCS say has changed...?

Comment: @Aaron I'm not using any. it's a simple personal standalone project..

Comment: Ramires Making use of a VCS is simple and this is a good example of where it can come in handy on any project...especially since it sounds like you want to expand the project and look for testers.

Comment: Did you check Event Viewer?  Do you have any messages there related to your app?

Comment: Remove all the try/catch statements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a classic example of when a [personal version control system](http://www.foldertrack.com) would have helped. It would have automatically kept every version of your code including the one right before you made the change that messed up your exe.

Anyway to fix your issue comment out the majority of the code untill it atleast runs. Add a simple output statement just to make sure it is doing something. Then slowly add back in more code.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I'm going to keep that in mind. regarding the commenting-out technique, I'll try that if nothing else works. What intrigues me is the apparition of a previously absent .application file, which is a clue that there was a change in how my deployment works, which could be co-relative to what I'm experiencing.

Comment: Yea and a personal version control system would have caught that configuration change that caused your deployment to stop generating the .application file

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to run your exe file in a consol (cmd.exe) to see if your application displays errors or exceptions in it.

Comment: It runs just the same. no errors reported, no additional information on the event viewer or anything.

Answer (score 0):

Check the `<YourAppName>.Exe.Config` file.

Probably it is not well-formed Xml.

Comment: I's a well-formed XML. I've wiped the debug and release folders entirely to prevent compiling errors to persist. Also re-compiled the whole application several times in an attempt to fix any simple problems like these.

Answer (score 0):

I'd start with removing the setup project from the solution, rebuilding then run it in debug mode.